# how do an action after click on browser forward button

Tags: jquery, html5-history

I have this code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.showcontainer').click(function(){
        $('.container').fadeIn();
        window.history.pushState('','','/test');
    });

    $('.container').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        window.history.back();
    });

    window.onpopstate = function(e) {
        $('.container').fadeOut();
    };
});
</script>

<input type="button" class="showcontainer" value="button">
<div class="container" style="display:none;width:500px;height:500px;background:red"></div>
```

Edit:

When I click on the `showcontainer` button, it shows me a container box and the url changes to '/test'. When I click on the container box or the browser back button, the container box hides and '/test' is deleted from the url.

When I click on the browser forward button, it only changes the url and doesn't show the container box.

I'd like the url to change to '/test' and the container box to appear when I click on the browser forward button. I don't know how do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run events when the pages go back and forward on history you want to pass object states and set conditionals like so:

```
$(function() {
    var stateObj = {
        page1: true,
        page2: false
    };
    window.history.pushState(stateObj, '', '');

    $('.showcontainer').click(function() {
        $('.container').fadeIn();
        stateObj.page1 = false;
        stateObj.page2 = true;
        window.history.pushState(stateObj, '', '/test');
    });

    $('.container').click(function() {
        window.history.back();
    });

    window.onpopstate = function(e) {
        var state = e.state;
        if (state.page1) {
            state.page1 = true;
            state.page2 = false;
            window.history.replaceState(state, '', '');
            $('.container').fadeOut();
        }
        if (state.page2) {
            state.page1 = false;
            state.page2 = true;
            window.history.replaceState(state, '', '');
            $('.container').fadeIn();
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: in default,  display property of container is none and dont need `$('.container').fadeOut();` in second row of your solution. after making history by pushstate() when I click on forward button, page dont refresh and only changes url but I want shows container box too.

Comment: ah i see.. in that case you need to mess around with the object youre passing to your state.. I will include an update on my answer.